# Why #pragmas are not part of the C++ standard?

Tags: macros

Usually the problem of having possible multiple inclusions is solved with a series of `#ifdef` `#ifndef` but the pragmas just solves this with a single line, apparently they are really useful and can make the code better in terms of readability.

Why they are not part of the C++ and C standards? there is a better way to avoid multiple inclusions?

Comment: You seems to be asking specifically about one use of `#pragma`, `#pragma once`. If that's the case you should change your question to make that explicit.

Comment: -1, you had time to read the comment, actually did it and did not react either. I remove the downvote after you have clarified the question.

Answer (score 6):

The very definition of `#pragma` is that they are non-Standard. Features which are provided as Standard are provided in some other way. Making `#pragma` Standard would defeat the purpose of, well, `#pragma`. They are nothing more than a set of implementation extensions, which happen to coincidentally be the same.

Comment: please see the my comment on the first answer.

Comment: @user827992: What about it?

Answer (score 3):

Because it is precisely targeted at specific compiler *implementation* therefore to support things that would *not* be part of the standards. Some compilers may elect to support conveniences such as you describe in their own way while others may not support them at all and still be standards compliant.

Comment: i don't get it; the entire C++ language depends on compiler implementations, also if you just consider for a moment a keyword like `inline` it' more a suggestion rather than a true command for the compiler; i do not think that you can guess the binary code that your source will generate before giving the "compile" command. I ask for the reason why they are not supported, i know that in today compilers they aren't, but what is the true reason.

Comment: The C++ language does not depend on a compiler existing *at all*.

Comment: ok, explain to me how inline works if you say that language is "not dependant" from the compiler.

Comment: inline is a C++ language keyword so any compiler will *compile* it. However it is totally up to the compiler *implementation* to honor it. Some compilers do, some don't and in this case the inline is simply ignored.

Comment: `inline`'s purpose has *nothing* to do with inlining. It's about ODR and multiple function definitions. Whether or not the compiler *actually* inlines the code is completely irrelevant and orthogonal.